# Express-Mongoose request-response cycle/error handling with exp

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I was under the impression that res.send() ends the request-response cycle, but without `return` in the else block, `next(ex)` is called which passes the response object to error handling middleware, resulting in `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Where is my understanding off? I am using `express-async-errors` to catch errors, if that's important.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  // get all staff sorted by name
  const allStaff = await Staff.find().sort('name');
  if (!allStaff) {
    res.status(404).send('No staff');
  } else {
    return res.status(200).send(allStaff);
  }
  next(ex);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you mention it yourselves that the next() function passes the response object to the error handling middleware, so the the next middleware will execute even if you dont want it to i.e allstaff would be sent succesfully but then the next() function would be invoked.

**What you are doing (without return in the else block):**

Sending the allstaff object and hence trying to end the request response cycle , but then calling  next() hence calling the next middleware which tries to mess up with what would otherwise have been a successful request response cycle.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  // get all staff sorted by name
  const allStaff = await Staff.find().sort('name');
  if (!allStaff) {
    res.status(404).send('No staff');
  } else {
   res.status(200).send(allStaff);   //send the response..expect the req-res cycle to end
  }
  next(ex);     //then call next which might try to hamper the outgoing response
});
```

**What you should do instead:**

If you send the response then in no way should it encounter other statement which tries to send the response again, I prefer the folloing code personally:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    // get all staff sorted by name
    Staff.find().sort('name').exec(function (err, docs) {     //this callback function will handle results
        if (err) {
            next();                                          //if there is an error..then the next middleware will end the req response cycle
        } else {                                             
            if (docs.length == 0) {
                res.status(404).send('No staff');           //send response,the req- res cycle ends,never disturbed again...story finished
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(docs);             //send response,the req- res cycle ends,never disturbed again.....story finished
            }
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was mistaken in thinking that res.send() also terminates a function like `return`. I really like how you've accounted for the case of an error first in your code, though wouldn't `res.status(200).send(allStaff);` result in undefined and would changing it to `docs` solve that problem? Also, is it useful to use async without await?

Comment: Oh! I am really, Just forgot to make these changes after copying your code. allStaff should have been replaced by docs, and there is no need of async since we are not using await anymore. I have edited it now....Happy coding!! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, and happy coding to you, as well : )